# selenium wait until x secs and if it passed x secs then reload the browser python

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.someurl.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)

def search_automation(keyword):
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".input_keyword").send_keys(keyword)

keyword_list = ['a','b','c']
for i in keyword_list:
    search_automation(i)
```

In the case of the code above, if the page is not loaded properly for 60 seconds, it just skips to the next keyword.

In real case that I'm working on, there are more than 10k of data to work with and I shouldn't miss any of them.

So, I want to put some if,else condition to the code which is abt waiting time.
is there any way I can put conditions to the waiting time?

For instance,

1. wait for 60 seconds max to find the element.
2. if finally 60 seconds passed, driver.close() and reload the driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WebDriverWait` in a `try` / `except` block here.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

def wait_for_element(by):
    try:
        # wait up to 60 seconds for the element
        WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(by))

        # if we hit exception, element was not found, and we should reload
    except TimeoutException():
        driver.refresh()
```

Just pass a selector such as `(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".input_keyword")` into the method. It will wait up to 60 seconds for the element to exist, and if it does not exist, it will refresh the page.

Comment: The exception is going to be a timeout exception, not no such element. WebDriverWait will wait for 60s and then timeout, throwing the exception.

Comment: its TimeoutException, not WebDriverTimeoutException.. I just updated the answer and also fixed the import,